# if statement returns wrong output when comparing KeyEvent .getText and index in array javafx

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to check if input (in the form of keypresses) from the user is the same as string `textToType` which has been broken down into a character array. The problem is even though they both return the same value, when I compare them it will still give the output `wrong letter`.

**Output**

```
index splitter [0] returned: t
event.getText returned: t
wrong letter
```

```java
@FXML
private void detectInputAreaKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    char[] splitter = textToType.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("index splitter [0] returned: " + splitter[0]);
    System.out.println("event.getText returned: " + event.getText());

    if (event.getText().equals(splitter[0])) {
        System.out.println("right letter");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("wrong letter");
    }
```

Comment: `event.getText()` is a `String`, whereas `splitter[0]` is a `char` (which gets autoboxed to a `Character`). Since they’re different types, they cannot possibly be equal. You can do either `event.getText().equals(textToType.substring(0,1))` or `event.getText().charAt(0) == splitter[0]`, etc.

Comment: Another not efficient way is to new String(splitter[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: you are comparing a `String` to a `char`, so they are not equal.

---

[`KeyEvent.getText()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getText()) returns a `String`, and `splitter[0]` is the primitive type `char`.

Since `String.equals(...)` expects an `Object`, so when you call

```
event.getText().equals(splitter[0])
```

`splitter[0]` is *autoboxed* to a wrapper object of type `Character`. Consequently, you are comparing a `String` to a `Character`. The [`String.equals()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) states

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null **and is a String object** ...

(my emphasis). Since you're providing a `Character` instance, not a `String` instance, the result of `equals()` is false.

You can fix this by comparing things of the same type:

```
if (event.getText().charAt(0) == splitter[0])
```

or

```
if (event.getText().equals(textToType.substring(0,1)))
```

(the first probably being marginally more efficient).